# How to sort data in file by date using python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I am currently working with a very large .txt file that contains seismic data. In my file, i have the ID number in the 1st column, the year in the 2nd, month in the 3rd, day in the 4th, hour in the 5th, minute in the 6th, second in the 7th, milliseconds in the 8th.

For example, here's a few lines from the .txt file:

[PICTURE OF EXAMPLE .TXT FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO9gS.png)

My goal is to sort the .txt file by the date. I would like the oldest events at the bottom and the most recent at the top. So, for example, if my data went down to 2000, i would like 2000 01 01 (etc.) to be at the bottom of the file and 2018 12 31 (etc.) at the top. Of course, each line is specific to an event, so i would like the rows to remain intact. Just reorganized by the date in descending order.

I have tried using .sort and have had no luck.[PICTURE OF CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lTwA.png)

This did not work the way i thought it would. It does not write the file correctly and it only sorts by year, when i would like it to sort the file by the entire date (year, month, day, hour, secs, millisec)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. Also [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

You can first add a new column with the `datetime` object like this:

```
df['datetime'] = df.apply(lambda row: datetime(row.year, row.month, row.day, row.hour, row.minute, row.second, row.millisec), axis=1)
```

Then you can sort by one column. (and maybe remove all the rest to free up the memory)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to just sort by multiple columns:

```
df.sort_values(by=df.columns[1:8].tolist(), ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

dates.sort(key = lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%d %b %Y'))

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Comment: in this we are sorting the list with date in ascending order with the hep of directive like % d(day of month), % b(month's locale abbreviated form) and %Y (year)

Comment: I meant to add it in the answer. You can do that by using the edit option just below the answer.